# Bayesian Network or Logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, bayesian, bayesian-network, propensity-scores, churn

The Bayesian Networks and Logistic regression can be used to predict events or give to each customer the propensity to have a behavior.

Which are the advantages or disadvantages of these 2 methods? When is better use the first and when is better use the other?

Answer (score 2):

A Bayesian network is a graphical representation of an arbitrary probabilistic model.   Logistic regression is one very specific kind of probabilistic model, and it can be represented by a Bayesian network.  So you can't really say that one is better than another at prediction.